# WPF ComboBox ignoring ToString override on ItemsSource objects

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, overriding, tostring

I have defined WatchList as follows:

```
// a named list of VariableWatchers
public class WatchList : List<VariableWatcher>
{
    private string _name;

    public WatchList(string name) : base()
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _name;
    }
}
```

I bound a list of WatchLists to the ItemsSource property of a ComboBox as follows:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="WatchListDropdown"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WatchLists}"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Margin="5"/>
```

"WatchLists" refers to the following property in my DataContext:

```
public IList<WatchList> WatchLists
{
    get { return _watchLists; }
}
```

Everything works great except that all of the entries in the list are showing up as "(Collection)" instead of the _name variable.  I put a breakpoint in ToString and confirmed that it is getting called at some point, and is returning the correct values, but somehow the ComboBox still shows "(Collection)".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why it's not using the ToString() override, but have you considered using DisplayMemberPath instead?

```
<ComboBox x:Name="WatchListDropdown"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WatchLists}"
      VerticalAlignment="Center"
      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
      Margin="5"/>
```

Of course you will need to adjust your object since binding needs either a public property or a dependency property.

```
private string _name;
public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  I am also confused as to why it is not using ToString, because that has always worked for me before.

Answer (score 0):

WatchLists is a collection of WatchList isn't it? So the Collection.ToString() will be called and displayed.

How about specifying the DisplayMemberPath to "name"? I hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

If the ItemsSource is bound to a single `WatchList`, which is of type `List<VariableWatcher>`, the actual collection displayed would be the list of `VariableWatcher`.

If the ItemsSource is bound to a collection of `WatchList` the .ToString() should override the default display. Of course, you can always create a property `Name` and make that the DisplayMember.